# error occur when sudo apt-get update

Tags: upgrade, updates, 64-bit, 14.04, 32-bit

Below error was occur after upgrading Ubuntu 14.04 from 13.01:

```
(gedit:15234): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/jez/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
jez@JEZZONEFLY:~$ sudo apt-get update
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                
忽略 http://archive.canonical.com saucy InRelease                              
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease                    
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease           
命中 http://archive.canonical.com saucy Release.gpg               
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease         
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease                     
命中 http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006 trusty Release.gpg      
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease          
命中 http://archive.canonical.com saucy Release                   
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease                                  
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                 
命中 http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006 trusty Release          
命中 http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Sources                        
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease                     
获取：1 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B]
命中 http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner amd64 Packages                 
命中 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release.gpg                   
命中 http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006 trusty/main amd64 Packages
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg       
获取：2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [933 B]
命中 http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner i386 Packages                  
命中 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release.gpg                   
命中 http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006 trusty/main i386 Packages
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                     
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release.gpg                                
获取：3 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [58.5 kB]             
命中 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release.gpg                                
命中 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release                                    
命中 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release                                    
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release                                    
命中 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release                                    
命中 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages                        
命中 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages                         
命中 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages                        
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release                        
命中 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages                         
获取：4 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release [58.5 kB]            
忽略 http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Translation-zh_CN              
忽略 http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006 trusty/main Translation-zh_CN        
忽略 http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Translation-zh               
忽略 http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006 trusty/main Translation-zh         
忽略 http://archive.canonical.com saucy/partner Translation-en               
忽略 http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006 trusty/main Translation-en         
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                             
命中 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages                        
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                       
命中 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages                         
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                         
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                       
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                      
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages                
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                  
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages                
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                       
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages                 
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                   
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages                 
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-zh_CN                   
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                      
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-zh_CN             
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en                
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-zh_CN             
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en                
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-zh_CN               
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                  
获取：5 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [3,405 B]        
获取：6 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [14 B]     
获取：7 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [648 B]      
获取：8 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [1,790 B]  
获取：9 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [10.1 kB] 
获取：10 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
获取：11 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,602 B]
获取：12 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [6,362 B]
获取：13 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [8,704 B] 
获取：14 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
获取：15 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [1,601 B]
获取：16 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [6,386 B]
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en              
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en        
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en        
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en          
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                   
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources             
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources               
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources             
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages            
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages      
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages         
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-zh_CN                     
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages      
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages             
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-zh                        
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages       
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages         
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en                        
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages       
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-zh_CN                     
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-zh                        
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en            
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en                        
错误 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main amd64 Packages                        
 404  Not Found
错误 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages                         
 404  Not Found
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en      
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-zh_CN                     
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-zh                        
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en      
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en                        
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-zh_CN                     
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en        
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-zh                        
获取：17 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [970 B]        
忽略 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en                        
获取：18 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [14 B]   
获取：19 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [14 B]     
获取：20 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [14 B]   
获取：21 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [977 B] 
获取：22 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
获取：23 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [14 B]
获取：24 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [14 B]
获取：25 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [977 B]  
获取：26 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
获取：27 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [14 B]
获取：28 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [14 B]
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
命中 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-zh                      
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-zh
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-zh
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-zh
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-zh_CN
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-zh
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-zh_CN
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-zh
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-zh_CN
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-zh
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-zh_CN
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-zh
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-zh_CN
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-zh
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-zh_CN
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-zh
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-zh_CN
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-zh
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-zh_CN
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-zh
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-zh_CN
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-zh
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-zh_CN
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-zh
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-zh_CN
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-zh
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-zh_CN
忽略 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-zh
下载 163 kB，耗时 1分 8秒 (2,387 B/s)
W: 无法下载 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: 无法下载 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when updating packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-updating-packages)

Answer (score 1):

mc3man's PPA doesn't contain packages for saucy anymore (that's why you get a 404).

As you are on trusty now, you can re-add the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: not saucy, it's trusty.

Comment: Yes, but he is using a PPA for saucy.

Comment: there isn't a ppa for specific Ubuntu version.This error will happen if PPA owner fails to add packages for the newer version say 14.04.

Comment: If I look [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu/dists/) I see a folder for trusty but not saucy, and in his URL is saucy. Wouldn't re-adding fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**Error 1:**

```
(gedit:15234): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/jez/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
```

Don't run gedit using `sudo`. Try to run graphical application using gksu.`gksu` package is not installed by default in Ubuntu. So try to install gksu by running the below command on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
gksu gedit filename
```

**Error 2:**

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

In your case just remove the not found `ppa:mc3man/trusty-media` ppa by running the below command on terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
```

To know more about 404 Not Found PPA's, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-updating-packages) question.